# Sending Multiple Emails PHP

Tags: php

It's a pretty straight forward question.

I have a php script that sends birthday wishes to all my customers. The subject of the mail is customized for each user(Happy Birthday, $name). Till now the script is working as it should be.

But I'm afraid that if the number of customers is very high, the execution time may cross the maximum execution time(which is 30 seconds).
Is there any solution to this so that my script doesn't stop before sending emails to all the customers ?

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: remove the execution time limit  and/or increase the efficiency of the script so it takes less time per-recipient. if you can't remove the time limit, then you'll have to split up the job so you run the script multiple times, each doing a few emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two different approaches to my problem.
As Fred -ii suggests, I can use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

This would cause the script to never timeout.

Or I can use the `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` function. ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php))

I can use set_time_limit(0); so that the script will run forever - however this is not recommended and my web server might catch me out with an imposed HTTP timeout (usually around 5 minutes). Since I've set up a cron job to send the mails, HTTP timeout shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use BCC headers in your php mail script [refer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108368)

before that check your mail server if they have any restriction on sending emails like [google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

Comment: exactly how would bccing help if each email is customized for every recipient?

Comment: BCC address are not shows to end user. add your email id into From address fields and To address field finally you can add some users to your BCC field.

Comment: Your solution would've worked if I had a static content to be sent over mail. But here, I am sending personalised content to each recipient. So using BCC headers won't do the trick.